# Sharepoint list with lookup column and condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a problem, I am not sure if I can have a SharePoint list with two lookup columns from another list, and then have a condition on the first lookup column (that basically has 3 choice values) to somehow filter and show the data in the second column, that was connected with the data in the first? Does anyone know is that possible?

Comment: You have to customize the list form using Power Apps for such requirements in SP online modern experience list forms.

Comment: Hope this case: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-cascade-multiple-lookups-column-in-PowerApps-for/td-p/1382600 and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdRgTnQ81OA&t=3s may help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible since you are working with SP-Online, you can apply some Cascading dropdown functionnalities in Power Apps which will allows you to filter the second lookup column based on the first lookup column value

see below the animated image, I believe this exactly what you are looking for :

[image]

First, we have two SharePoint lists :

- Locations (Address, Region, Country)
- Regional Classification (Country, Region)

[image]

Now, in your Power Apps customized form, apply the following logic :

1- Be sure that you have add the required data source lists :

[image]

2- In Region's Combobox, update the Items property with the following formula :

```
Distinct('Regional Classifications',Region)
```

3- in Region's card, in the Update property apply the following formula :

```
LookUp(Choices([@Locations].Region),Value = inputRegion.Selected.Result)
```

4- in Country's combobox, update the Items property with the following formula :

```
Filter('Regional Classifications',Region=inputRegion.Selected.Result).Title
```

5- in Country's card, in the Update property apply the following formula :

```
LookUp(Choices([@Locations].Country),Value = inputCountry.Selected.Title)
```

and that's it !

Cordially.

Comment: I have implemented what you said in power apps and it looks like it works, but the problem now is that it doesn't write anything in the sharepoint list.

Comment: you are using Power Apps forms ?

Comment: Yes yes, it is power apps, and when I go into the edit screen it allows me to choose how i want and when I save and finish it doesn't write anything in the detail screen or in the sharepoint list.

Comment: can we have a call and you share your screen ?

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation, yes we can, when are you available?

Comment: https://www.spguides.com/powerapps-cascading-dropdown/

Comment: check this link

Comment: I tried this link but it still doesn't write it from the power app to Sharepoint list, the problem is that I have two columns that are lookup in the second Sharepoint list in the first I have these two columns, maybe that is why it did not work.

Comment: wait, can you explain further ? if i understand well you have the following situation : 
List1 : Title, LookUpColumn1, LookUpColumn2
List2, List3

Comment: The fields LookUpColumn1 and LookUpColumn2 bring data from List2, List3 respectively right ?

Comment: Yes I have List1 with 2 columns process and people, and then in the List2 I have LookUpColumn1 and LookUpColumn2 for those 2 columns, and when I insert the instructions that you gave me in the power apps it filters the column people by process but it doesn't write it into the sharepoint list.

Comment: because you need to do another lookup function inside that input in Power Apps

Comment: So if I understand I need another field in the power apps to lookup the field that is filtered?

Comment: not really, you just need to customize your OnUpdate property, that's all. I will share an answer asap

Comment: Okay, please when you can share an answer.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Hello I used this answer that you gave me and it works so thanks a lot but it has a little bug, I was wondering can we have a call so that I can share you my screen so that you can see what is the small problem here?

Comment: I was just wondering since this second column that is filtered I added a small correction so that it can select multiple values and when I click save it only stores the last value I selected, can I somehow add something to the update code so that it can store all values?

Comment: Currently I am outside my desk, I will let you know when I will be available for a call, email me here : boulahia.aimen@gmail.com

Comment: https://youtu.be/Qzpjq008cBY Hey, I found this video is interesting for your case